# JwtBearer asp net core get signing key from api

Tags: asp.net-core, jwt

Is it possible to configure JwtBearer from asp.net-core that it can take signing key (in my case public key) required to verify is user is authorized?

I have somehing like this:

```
        services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddJwtBearer(o =>
            {
                o.BackchannelHttpHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
                o.MetadataAddress = "http://auth-server.local.com/api";
                o.Authority = "http://localhost:5000";
                o.Audience = "http://localhost:5001";
                o.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                o.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {   
                    IssuerSigningKey = "here should be public key exposed by my auth api server"
                    ValidIssuer = "http://localhost:5000",
                    ValidAudience = "http://loclhost:5001"
                };
            })
            ;
```

but my client does not call my auth api in order to obtain public key.

Comment: The signing key is your applications private key. You use it to sign a JWTtoken and dispense that token. When someone calls your application with a token - the application checks if the token was signed using the value specified in IssuerSigningKey - Maybe elaborate more on what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: I have AuthService which can create token after user is authenticated successfully. This token is created using RSA. If any user's call request e.g to orders.service, this request must be autorized. But I want to avoid calls to auth server, so If my auth server can expose public key via some kind of api, the order.service would can validate token by itselft

Comment: Hmm... -1 because ???

Comment: Hey @bielu000 just wanted to let you know that I have the same question and sadly it seems the people responding have no idea what they are talking about. For now I'm just doing a call to the auth service before setting up the WebHostBuilder, but I'd like to be able to change the public key if the auth service needs new certs.

Comment: Same question here...found any way of implementation?

Answer (score -1):

The code you have there just tells your applications that you want to USE JWT Tokens for authentication and what parameters to validate incoming requests (with tokens) with.

You need to setup and endpoint now to issue those tokens.. or "public key" as you put it.

Your code (notice the "mysecret" in the issuer)

```
  services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddJwtBearer(o =>
            {
                o.BackchannelHttpHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
                o.MetadataAddress = "http://auth-server.local.com/api";
                o.Authority = "http://localhost:5000";
                o.Audience = "http://localhost:5001";
                o.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                o.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {   
                    IssuerSigningKey = "MySecret"
                    ValidIssuer = "http://localhost:5000",
                    ValidAudience = "http://loclhost:5001"
                };
            })
            ;
```

Now in a controller:

```
public class AccountController : Controller
    {
 [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult getKey()
        {
                    var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("MySecret"));
                    var creds = new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);

                    var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
                        issuer: "http://localhost:5000",
                        audience: "http://localhost:5001",
                        expires: DateTime.Now.AddYears(10),
                        signingCredentials: creds);

return Json(token);
}
}
```

Notice how in the services.. You set the private key to "MySecret" - this tells the application that any token used with a request.. must be signed with this value. Otherwise it rejects it.

In the controller.. We create a key with the same "MySecret" and issue it at host/account/getkey

Now - just add the [Authorize] tag to any function or controller you want to protect.

```
   [Authorize]
     [HttpPost]
            public IActionResult Test()
            {
    }
```

EDIT: It appears you want some kind of permanent token. Just set the expires field in the new JWTtoken() line to expire in 1000 years or whatever and publicly broadcast that to whomever you want. Albiet - this is an insecure authorization model.

Comment: I'm not using symethric key... I'm using RSA, so in theory each microservice can validate token itself, after obtain PUBLIC KEY from AuthService.

Comment: You cant configure the service .AddJWTBearer() to work with RSA.. Easily from my unserstanding but i cant help you there.

Comment: Take a look at this and you will understand what I'm want to archive https://developer.okta.com/blog/2018/03/23/token-authentication-aspnetcore-complete-guide